# auctex does not parse own sty file

Tags: auctex

a own sty file is not parsed to find commands, it means they can not use with C-c C-m

I use the following .emacs

```
(load "auctex.el" nil t t)
(load "preview-latex.el" nil t t)
(require 'tex-site)
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
(setq TeX-save-query nil)
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t) 
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8-unix)
```

This is a test sty file (test.sty)

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{test}
  [2013/03/19 v0.01 LaTeX package for my own purpose]
\newcommand{\mysecondtest}{My second test}
```

And this is my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{test}
\newcommand{\myfirsttest}{My first test}
\begin{document}
\myfirsttest{}
\end{document}
```

With C-c C-m I can use only myfirsttest, but not mysecondtest. What can I do, to use the own commands with auctex? I use auctex 11.87 and emacs23 23.4+1-4 on Debian Linux.

Thanks for helpful hints

Comment: You need to run `TeX-auto-generate` on your `.sty` file to extract the information.

Comment: Is there a file `test.el` in a subdirectory called `save`?  If not, is one created if you edit and save `test.sty`?  If so, do you still have the same problem?

Comment: is there a way, to automatic run TeX-auto-generate if the .sty file was changed?

Comment: Is it possible, to include with auctex not only the command (defined with \newcommand), but instead of it the entire block (it means "My first test" instead of \myfirsttest{}?

Comment: @Micha: To your first question, left to its own devices, Auctex generates its style files every time you edit and save a .tex or .sty file.  `TeX-auto-generate` will force this to happen even if you do not edit anything, and there are ways to make this happen every time Auctex looks into a directory.  To your second question: I'm not quite sure what you are after, but maybe you should raise that as a new question.

Comment: Andrew Swann and Charles Stewart give the right hint (IMO). You should probably have a call to `TeX-auto-generate` somewhere in your init files to ensure AUCTeX's styles database is (re)built. Also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410393/how-to-properly-set-up-auctex-to-parse-macros-from-my-own-sty-files

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the algorithm that Auctex applies to generate style files, which it uses to characterise the commands available via `C-c C-m`, can fail to see that a command has been generated.

Left to its own devices, Auctex generates its style files every time you edit and save a .tex or .sty file.  `TeX-auto-generate` will force this to happen even if you do not edit anything, and there are ways to make this happen every time Auctex looks into a directory.

(Hoisted from comment, per Joseph's request)