# How to properly set up AUCTeX to parse macros from my own *.sty files?

Tags: emacs, auctex, auto-completion

I am on Windows. Here is the code I have in my `.emacs` file to enable AUCTeX to recognize macros I have defined in my own style files:

```lisp
(setq TeX-parse-self t) ; Enable parse on load.
(setq TeX-auto-save t) ; Enable parse on save.
(setq-default TeX-master nil); https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html
(setq TeX-auto-regexp-list t); https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47385/adding-custom-macros-to-completion-list-with-auctex
(setq TeX-auto-parse-length 999999)
(setq TeX-macro-private
      (list
        "./"
        "C:/Users/LilMonkey/texmf/tex/latex/local"))
```

Logic:

- [TeX-auto-generate should be running](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103224/auctex-does-not-parse-own-sty-file) because of `(setq TeX-parse-self t)` and `(setq TeX-auto-save t)`
- other variables set [based on suggestions given in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47416/49339)
- `(setq-default TeX-master nil)` based on AUCTeX manual's recommendation, but I don't actually see AUCTeX querying me for the master file; I have tried variations where this line is commented out, but no difference exists

Anyway, I still don't get auto-completion options for macros I have defined in my own `*.sty` files under `C:/Users/LilMonkey/texmf/tex/latex/local`. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the way `TeX-auto-generate` is invoked:

- `TeX-auto-generate` should be running because of `(setq TeX-parse-self t)` and `(setq TeX-auto-save t)`

  With these 2 variables set, AUCTeX only parses the current .tex file and its master or child files.  It also parses the packages loaded via `\usepackage` and loads `<package-name>.el` if it finds one.  AUCTeX doesn't recursively run `TeX-auto-generate` on packages for which it doesn't find a style file.

  Looking at [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002dauto_002dgenerate), there is:

  > Command: **`TeX-auto-generate TEX AUTO`**
  >   <kbd>M-x TeX-auto-generate RET</kbd>
  >   Generate style hook for *TEX* and store it in *AUTO*. If *TEX* is a
  >   directory, generate style hooks for all files in the directory.

  Try <kbd>M-x TeX-auto-generate RET c:/Users/LilMonkey/texmf/tex/latex/local/ RET</kbd>.  The results should be then in the directory defined in `TeX-auto-private`.  Note: Consider the parsed results as a starting point, you might have to touch them.
- other variables set [based on suggestions given in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47416/49339)

  I consider this line to be harmful:
  `(setq TeX-auto-regexp-list t)`

  Again from [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002dauto_002dregexp_002dlist-1):

  > Variable: **`TeX-auto-regexp-list`**
  >
  > List of regular expressions matching TeX macro definitions.
  >
  > The list has the following format ((REGEXP MATCH TABLE) …), that is, each entry is a list with three elements.
  >
  > REGEXP. Regular expression matching the macro we want to parse.
  >
  > MATCH. A number or list of numbers, each representing one parenthesized subexpression matched by REGEXP.
  >
  > TABLE. The symbol table to store the data. This can be a function, in which case the function is called with the argument MATCH. Use
  >   TeX-match-buffer to get match data. If it is not a function, it is
  >   presumed to be the name of a variable containing a list of match data.
  >   The matched data (a string if MATCH is a number, a list of strings if
  >   MATCH is a list of numbers) is put in front of the table.

  I suggest you don't touch this one as it has a sensible default (`TeX-auto-full-regexp-list`).

  The next line
  `(setq TeX-auto-parse-length 999999)`
  is also not necessary since you're repeating the default.
- `(setq-default TeX-master nil)` based on AUCTeX manual's recommendation, but I don't actually see AUCTeX querying me for the master file

  AUCTeX will not ask if it finds `TeX-master` set in the local variables of your .tex file.  Edit that entry manually and hit <kbd>C-c C-n</kbd>.