# How do I tell AUCteX about custom macros AND included packages?

Tags: emacs, auctex

Similar questions have been asked before so this post may be a duplicate of:

- [How to properly set up AUCTeX to parse macros from my own *.sty files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410393/how-to-properly-set-up-auctex-to-parse-macros-from-my-own-sty-files)
- [auctex does not parse own style file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103224/auctex-does-not-parse-own-sty-file)
- [Adding custom macros to completion list with AUCTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47385/adding-custom-macros-to-completion-list-with-auctex/)

I have tried to follow the advice given in the posts linked above, and had partially working support for my custom macros - but now something in my AucTeX setup appears to be broken and I am reaching out for help.

My setup is the following:

I use Emacs 27.2 with AucTeX 13.0.15. In my `TEXMFHOME` directory, there is a subfolder (`~/texmf/tex/latex/local/hvw`) containing the following style file `hvw.sty`

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{hvw}[2021/12/14 package hvw]

\input{hvw-packages.tex}
\input{hvw-macros.tex}
% ...

\endinput
```

, as well as several `.tex` files containing packages, macros, colors, etc.

The file `hvw-packages.tex` contains packages to be loaded

```latex
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{siunitx}
\RequirePackage{algorithm2e}
% ...
```

whereas `hvw-macros.tex` contains some custom macros:

```latex
\DeclareDocumentCommand\email{m}{\href{mailto:#1}{\textcolor{rwth-blue}{\texttt{#1}}}}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\setdef{mo}{\left\{#1\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{ \mid #2}\right\}}
% ...
```

In my `init.el`, I have set the following variables:

```lisp
(use-package tex
  :ensure auctex
  :init
  (setq-default TeX-master nil)
  ; ...
  :custom
  (TeX-auto-save t)
  (TeX-parse-self t)
  (TeX-macro-private '("./"
                       "~/texmf/tex/latex/local/hvw"))
  ; ...
)
```

I have also run `TeX-auto-generate` multiple times on `~/texmf/tex/latex/local/`, and I can see its output in my `TeX-auto-private` directory ... but if open a `.tex` document with `\usepackage{hvw}` in the preamble:

- Inserting my custom macros via `TeX-insert-{macro|environment}` used to work until recently and now it no longer works at all.
- Inserting macros or environments via `TeX-insert-{macro|environment}` only works for *some* of the packages listed in `hvw-packages.tex`:

  - for the `amsmath` package, everything seems to be fine.
  - for `siunitx`, I only get some of the macros as completion candidates, namely `\sisetup`, `\DeclareSI{Unit|Power|Prefix|Qualifier}`. The more common macros `\SI` and `\si` are now missing which is extremely confusing to me.
  - for the `algorithm2e` package, no completion is provided at all.

Any help with this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Which AUCTeX version are you using?  Maybe 13.0.15 from ELPA?

Comment: Yes, indeed, I'm using version `13.0.15`. (I could have sworn that I had included that info in my original post ... have added it now). Is this a known issue?

Comment: Huh.

The most confusing aspect of my problem - partial macro completion of `siunitx` - has resolved on its own. I am still using auctex `13.0.15` so I cannot really point out the reason but I won't complain.

For my remaining issues
- no completion for candidates for custom macros
- no completion for some latex packages, such as `algorithm2e`, `optidef`, etc.
I will once again check out the advice given in other posts.

Answer (score 1):

AUCTeX 13.0.15 introduced some changes which might be relevant for the issues you're facing.  For the easy part:

- *for `siunitx`, I only get some of the macros as completion candidates, namely `\sisetup`, `\DeclareSI{Unit|Power|Prefix|Qualifier}`. The more common macros `\SI` and `\si` are now missing which is extremely confusing to me.*
  This is due to premature removal of deprecated macros.  This is fixed in version 13.0.16 which is already released.
- *for the `algorithm2e` package, no completion is provided at all*
  AUCTeX relies on its own style files in order to provide completion.  You can have a look for them in [this directory](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/tree/style).  There are currently no `algorithm2e.el` or `optidef.el`.

For this part:

- *Inserting my custom macros via `TeX-insert-{macro|environment}` used to work until recently and now it no longer works at all.*
  It is hard to tell if a change in `xparse.el` is relevant.  Maybe you open up a new question showing the content of your `hvw-macros.el` and then try to find out what's going wrong.